# How to get one object in a class to modify another in the same class in python?

Tags: python, class

I have a class in python, and I'd like to be able to do an operation to one object and have that operation in turn identify another object to change and in turn modify it.  To make this concrete:

Say we have a bunch of locations (the objects), and each location has some things (call them elements).  I would like to tell location `1` to move one of its elements to the right by `location.move_right(element)`.  It should then add that element to location `2`.  (in my actual problem, the "location" would need to calculate which location it will move to, and so I don't know a priori where it's going.)

Here is the working code I have.  Within the class I've placed a dictionary that will hold all objects that have been created.  I can imagine this could cause trouble for garbage collection etc.  I suspect there is a better way.  Is there?

```
class location(object):
    locations = {}
    def __init__(self, coordinate):
        self.locations[coordinate]=self
        self.coord = coordinate
        self.elements = set()

    def add_element(self, element):
        self.elements.add(element)

    def move_right(self, element):
        self.elements.remove(element)
        new_location = self.locations[self.coord+1]
        new_location.add_element(element)

x = location(1)
y=location(2)
x.add_element('r')
x.move_right('r')
```

Comment: you should specify `location.locations` instead of `self.locations`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what is the reasoning behind your suggestion beyond making more clear that locations is a class variable? I mean he is currently not assigning to locations, so for me it seems okay to have it like this. Additionally this way he is protected from a potential class renaming.

Comment: To me, it doesn't make sense to have this functionality in the `Location` class. Make some `LocationContainer` that encapsulates this logic.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you expand a bit on how I should do that?

Comment: I don't know enough about your project to really say anything concrete. In any event, if you are just trying to avoid memory leaks, use a [`weakref.WeakValueDictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary)